# Laravel Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update my data in the DB, but I keep getting a error.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Here is my code:

```
public function postTodo( Request $request ){
    if ( $request->input('action') == 'set_as_done' ){
        $thing = DB::Table('todo')->where('id', $request->input('id'));
        if ( $thing ){
            $thing->done = $request->input('set_as_done');
            $thing->save();
        }
        return redirect(route('admin.todo'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do `$thing->save()`, `$thing` must be instance of model that extends `Model` or `Ardent`.

When you do `$thing = DB::Table('todo')->where('id', $request->input('id'));` the `$thing` variable is a collection, not related to a model.

You must make a model for `Thing.php` then you can do this:

```
$thing = Thing::where('id', $request->input('id'));
if ( $thing ){
    $thing->done = $request->input('set_as_done');
    $thing->save();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

save method works on Eloquent model not on builder so your code needs to fire update query instead of save

i would suggest create Eloquent model todo and then write code with save() method which makes more sense than using builder

```
public function postTodo( Request $request ){
    if ( $request->input('action') == 'set_as_done' ){
        $thing = DB::table('todo')->where('id', $request->input('id'))->first();
        if ( $thing ){
            DB::table('todo')->where('id', $request->input('id'))->update([
                'set_as_done' => $request->input('set_as_done')
            ]);
        }
        return redirect(route('admin.todo'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create model for table todo using php artisan make:model TodoModel.

```
<?php namespace App; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; class Todo extends Model{ protected $table = 'todo'; }
```

After that you can use Todo to save your data.

```
public function postTodo( Request $request ){
if ( $request->input('action') == 'set_as_done' ){
    $thing = Todo->find('id', $request->input('id'));
    if ( $thing ){
        $thing->set_as_done = $request->input('set_as_done')
        $thing->save();
    }
    return redirect(route('admin.todo'));
}
```

}